# How do I change my PYTHONPATH , after I just installed a python virtualenv?

Tags: linux, unix, python

So I created a virutal environment.  I also sourced it.  Then I installed some packages.

Now, I want to change my  PYTHONPATH. How?

Comment: Same way as every other environment variable?

Comment: usually, I change the file in /etc/profile.  But how do I do that in virtualenv? What do I add ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always change your PYTHONPATH even by request, adding the PYTHONPATH before executing the code or loading your virtual env

`PYTHONPATH=blablabla; program execution`

You can also change your PYTHONPATH globally in `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969553/can-i-automatically-change-my-pythonpath-when-activating-deactivating-a-virtualen) question and answers which give information on how to do this.